# How to plot the solution of a Partial Differential Equation?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration, complex, homework

**My attempt.**

I need to solve numerically the [Complex Ginzburg-Laudau Equation](http://codeinthehole.com/static/tutorial/index.html) (CGLE):
$$ \frac{\partial A}{\partial t}=\epsilon A-(1+i\beta)|A|^2A+(1+i\alpha)\nabla^2A $$
I'm using a uniform initial condition $A(x,y,t=0)=1$ and periodic boundary conditions: $A(-x_m/2,y,t)=A(x_m/2,y,t)$, $A(x,-y_m/2,t)=A(x,y_m/2,t)$, where I'm defining the domain $\mathcal{D}=\{(x,y):-x_m/2\leq x\leq x_m/2,-y_m/2\leq y\leq y_m/2\}$ with $t\in [0,t_m]$.

My code is the following: (parameters obtained [here](http://codeinthehole.com/static/tutorial/2D.html))

```
(*Parameters.*)
ϵ = 1;
α = 0;
β = 1.5;
xM = 50;
yM = 50;
tM = 10000;

(*Numerical solution*)
sol = NDSolve[{D[A[x, y, t], t] == ϵ A[x, y, t] - (1 + I β)
Norm[A[x, y, t]]^2 A[x, y, t] + (1 + I α) Laplacian[A[x, y, t], {x, y}],
A[x, y, 0] == 1, A[-xM/2, y, t] == A[xM/2, y, t], A[x, -yM/2, t] ==
A[x, yM/2, t]}, A, {x, -xM/2, xM/2}, {y, -yM/2, yM/2}, {t, 0, tM}]
```

with the out:

[image]

Then I try to plot with:

```
(*Plotting*)
DensityPlot[Evaluate[Re[A[x, y, 10000]] /. sol], {x, -xM/2 + 1, 
xM/2 - 1}, {y, -yM/2 + 1, yM/2 - 1}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

but I just obtain an odd graphic:

[image]

I'm supposed to obtain a frozen picture of the following (see [here](http://codeinthehole.com/static/tutorial/2D.html)):

[image]

**Question.** What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your TeX equation and the *Mathematica* equation are different.  The Tex has `Abs[A[x, y, t]]^2` and the code has  `Norm[A[x, y, t]]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 You're right. I just edited the code (Norm[A] and Abs[A] give the same result for a complex A: Sqrt[Re[A]^2+Im[A]^2]). BTW I'm still getting the same blue square after the correction.

Comment: There's no difference between `Norm` and `Abs` on 1D vectors/scalars.  `Norm` is meant (in *Mathematica*) for vectors and `Abs` for scalars.  (For example `Norm[{x, y}]` evaluates to `Sqrt[Abs[x]^2 + Abs[y]^2]`.)  So `Abs` seems more consistent with *Mathematica* idiom, but it makes no difference in the result. -- What version are you using?  I did not get a blue square in the original code.  I get a convergence error and `NDSolve` quits before `t` gets past `t == 1` or so with the new code.

Comment: Actually, `NDSolve` does not consistently stop at the same time `t` each time I try it.  Strange.  I'm using to it being deterministic.  I just stopped at `t = 8.42`, much farther than any earlier trial run.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'm using Mathematica 10, student edition. And I ran the exact same code using Norm and the correct value of $\beta=1.5$, and I got the same blue square.

Comment: If I replace `Norm[_]^2` with `_ * Conjugate[_]` I get a convergence error extremely quickly, always at `t==0.9567275319519298``.  Replacing it with `Abs[_]^2` gives me an error at `t < 0.025` after some time, and using `Norm[_]^2` gives me an error at `t < 10` after a long time.  Mathematica 10.0.0.0, Windows 8.1 64-bit.

Answer (score 3):

The differential equation, its initial condition, and its boundary conditions are translationally invariant in space.  Consequently, the solution must be independent of `x` and `y`.  Indeed, solving the equations as given in the Question does give a spatially constant solution that oscillates in time.  For instance,

```
DensityPlot[Evaluate[Re[A[x, y, 10000]] /. sol], {x, -xM/2, xM/2}, {y, -yM/2, 
  yM/2}, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

gives a constant color plot.  (Note that omitting `ColorFunctionScaling -> False` yields a blotchy plot that varies in time, but this spatial variation is nothing but tiny roundoff errors.)

A segment of the time history at any spatial position is given by

```
Plot[Evaluate[Re[A[0, 0, t]] /. sol], {t, 9000, 9100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

It seems likely that you did not obtain the pattern shown in your animation, because the animation was produced using different initial conditions.

Incidentally, I find it strange that NDSolve produces the error message,

```
NDSolve::eerr: Warning: scaled local spatial error estimate of 151.69068701912053` at t = 10000.` in the direction of independent variable x is much greater than the prescribed error tolerance. Grid spacing with 15 points may be too large to achieve the desired accuracy or precision. A singularity may have formed or a smaller grid spacing can be specified using the MaxStepSize or MinPoints method options. >>
```

because the solution is well behaved there and, as noted earlier, constant in space up to tiny roundoff errors.

Comment: I think the is error is because it is so flat.  Since it is a scaled estimate, the noise is magnified (I think).

Comment: @MichaelE2  I would have expected the error to be scaled to the RMS value of the solution.  In any case, I have run the 1D (in time) calculation and the error message goes away.

Comment: I just changed my initial condition for $A(x,y,t=0)=\sin (x)$, and also changed the domain for $\{(x,y): -\pi \leq x \leq \pi, -\pi \leq y \leq \pi \}$ keeping the periodic boundary conditions. But now, for tM=100, I get this "Maximum number of 51693 steps reached at the point t == 0.00217" and "Warning: scaled local spatial error estimate of 366.156
at t = 0.00217". What could it be? @MichaelE2